# Can I use Kubuntu Live CD to install kubuntu-desktop package on a Ubuntu installation?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, live-cd, offline

I have got Ubuntu and Kubuntu live CD ISO. I installed Ubuntu on My Machine. But I want to install `kubuntu-desktop` package to try KDE. But this is a huge Internet download, which I do not afford. Can I use my existing Kubuntu-Live-CD to install `kubuntu-desktop` package on my existing Ubuntu installation ?.

Comment: If you want `kubuntu-desktop`.... Wouldn't it be a better solution to just install Kubuntu?

Comment: @RobinJ, Thanks for your advice, but I want them both running in a single installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make two directory to mount the iso and squashfs filesystem.

### Part 1: Get all required deb files

Open the terminal and execute these :

```
mkdir /tmp/iso  
mkdir /tmp/filesystem
```

Then mount the iso and the live filesystem inside the iso:

```
sudo mount -o loop <path-to-iso-file/kubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso> /tmp/1  
sudo mount -o loop /tmp/iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs /tmp/filesystem
```

Then make a directory to create all the dependencies of kubuntu-desktop package

`mkdir ~/kubuntu-desktop-repacked` , I assume you have created this in your home directory.

Then issue this command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

and copy the packages name after the line `The following NEW packages will be installed:`

you can save the packages name in a new file.

Then generate all the required packages by this command, *(make sure you are in a folder for repackaged files, in this case 'kubuntu-desktop-repacked' )*

```
sudo dpkg-repack --root=/tmp/filesystem <all-the-names-of-packages-you-copied>
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, wait until it finishes.

### Part 2: Create a local repository

Now you have all the deb files required for `kubuntu-desktop` package. you need to install these packages now from your local computer, to do this, you need to setup a local repository.

Open a terminal and `cd` to the folder where all the deb files reside. *(here, kubuntu-desktop-repacked)*

Now Issue this command in the terminal

```
apt-ftparchive packages . > Packages
```

This will create a file with the name `Packages` which `apt` will use to get information about your local repository.

Now open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with administrative power, to inform `apt` that you have a local repository with neccessary packages.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

will open gedit with the files, it should have already many repository line already.

At the top of file, add the following line and save and close the file.

```
deb file:/home/<path-to-debs-folder> /
```

replace  with the actual path in your newly repacked debs folder.

In this example this is `/home/anwar/kubuntu-desktop-repacked` *(My user name is `anwar`, of course your's may be different)*.

Now issue this command in the terminal to install your desired package_(kubuntu-desktop)_

```
sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated kubuntu-desktop
```

This will install all the packages.

#### Note 1: Trusted repository

This example uses an untrusted local repository, so we issue `--allow-unauthenticated` switch to the `apt-get`. You can create a trusted repository also for this same purpose. See the reference line below.

Reference: [trusted repository](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090731).

#### Note 2: Still wants to download packages

If you still need to download some other packages, this can be the result of the updates of the online repository. If a package has an updated version on the online repository , the `apt` system will try to install that package first.  **The solution** is disable the main repository doing `software-properties-gtk` command.

Open terminal, type `sudo software-properties-gtk` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then remove the tick marks from **main** an **universe** repository. also disable the update repository in the **updates** tab
Then update the repository cache by doing this
`sudo apt-get update` , you should now install package from your local repository.

#### Note 3: Showing broken dependency error

If you already installed some KDE software *(usually starts with 'K' letter, such as `kate` or `kile`)* and the installed softwares are updated version of the packages included in the Live CD, and You disables the **main** and **universe** repository from solution of Note 2, You will face a broken dependency error which says "Some packages depends on some other packages, but that packages cannot be installed".

To solve this you can try adding the `-t <release>` switch to `apt-get` command.  such as
`sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated kubuntu-desktop -t precise`,
replace `precise` with your release (oneiric, or natty, or lucid).

**If this does not solves your problem**, then enable the **main** and **universe** repository again. It will definitely download some packages (**updated**), but that download will not be huge.

#### Note 4: Installing dpkg-repack

If you do not have `dpkg-repack` program, you can install it via terminal by simply issuing this

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
```

Comment: I tried this but the md5 of the rebuilt package didn't match with the original package offered by distribution. Is there anyway to rebuild the package with md5 matching.

Comment: This isn't a problem because the packages are good enough. The md5sum didn't match and won't match because `dpkg-repack` put a custom line in the package descriptions. You can then create a local repository with these packages and install from them.

Comment: yes. But i have a different situation. I'm trying to build an alternate cd from live cd through jigdo-lite. I need packages from live cd, so i used dpkg-repack to get the deb packages. But they don't match the original md5 (or hex) which is very essential for jigdo to recognise the files. That is why i want to have the same original package. Is it possible to remove what dpkg-repack adds to the package. And the file size built by dpkg-repack seems to be less than the original file. Totally confused..