# Is it possible to install LibreOffice from Ubuntu DVD to Ubuntu studio?

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, dvd, ubuntu-studio

Because of download restriction, I would like to know if it is possible to install LibreOffice (or other software) from Ubuntu 12.04 DVD to Ubuntu studio?

I have Ubuntu studio 12.04 installed and have Ubuntu 12.04 DVD.

Comment: you mean **from** ubuntu 12.04 DVD **to**  Ubuntu studio. Not via internet. right?

Comment: Sorry about my bad english, yes, from ubuntu 12.04 DVD to Ubuntu studio

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has Libreoffice when installing, while ubuntu-studio has not by default, when i insert ubuntu dvd, a synaptic package manager opens, may be possible to get Libreoffice from ubuntu cd or dvd.

Answer (score 0):

In short answer - **No, You can't**. Because the openoffice is installed in the Live filesystem of Ubuntu DVD ( they are not in .deb format)

Long answer - yes. You can use the installed packages in the Live filesystem by repacking those packages, This is a complicated way ( but, I  used this method once ) See the question [Can I use Kubuntu Live CD to install kubuntu-desktop package on a Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135511/can-i-use-kubuntu-live-cd-to-install-kubuntu-desktop-package-on-a-ubuntu-install) for details

Comment: Seems possible, thanks, I will try and let you know, thanks again.

Comment: Well since i am beginner, I am confueing, so I will download later when i extended my download limitation, Thanks for answers.

Comment: @Ali have you tried the answer ?